# Image is not showing on ImageButton for app:actionViewClass

Tags: android

I implemented sorting functionality for users. I used Image button in my menu file, but it is not showing actual image.

Current Screenshot (See next to search image on toolbar):

[image: not showing actual sort image]

Expected Screenshot:

[image: this]

Code:

**menu_sort:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/filter"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_sort_black_24dp"
        android:title="Filter"
        app:actionViewClass="android.widget.ImageButton"
        app:showAsAction="always">

    </item>
</menu>
```

**MainActivity:**

```
  @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_fragment_search, menu);
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_sort, menu);

        ImageButton locButton = (ImageButton) menu.findItem(R.id.filter).getActionView();
        locButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showPopup(v);
            }
        });
        return true;
    }


 public void showPopup(View view) {
        PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(this, view, R.style.PopupMenu);
        popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup_menu_sort, popup.getMenu());
        popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
        popup.show();
    }


  @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.ascending:
                sendOrderBy(ASECNDING);
                getViewPagerPosition(ASECNDING);
                break;

            case R.id.descending:
                sendOrderBy(DESCNDING);
                getViewPagerPosition(DESCNDING);
                break;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

**popup_menu_sort:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/ascending"
        android:title="A-Z"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/descending"
        android:title="Z-A"/>

</menu>
```

**Please Note:** Please don't tell me to do this any other ways like item inside group or you can do in single file, I know that. Why I change because of Popup style for theme. Yes, it is necessary to build my own Popup menu. It's my requirement and I can not change it. So don't suggest me to do that without own popup menu and use default menu.

Answer (score 0):

Why you are treating menu item as the image button you can do like this.

**menu_sort**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:id="@+id/filter"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_sort_black_24dp"
    android:title="Filter"
    app:showAsAction="always">

</item>
```

**MainActivity :**

```
  @Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_sort, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);


    menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.filter);
    // count=0;
    // notify1();
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.filter) {
    View menuView = findViewById(R.id.filter); // SAME ID AS MENU ID
    showPopup(menuView);
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

use your show pop up like this

[this is output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvFxQ.jpg)

Comment: That is the problem my dear! I can't create my own popup menu without view parameter. see the showPopup method.

Comment: @KavyaKashyap I put my output screenshot. please check out and tell me if you have another question.

Answer (score 0):

Hope following steps will be useful to you.

- Remove this line: `app:actionViewClass="android.widget.ImageButton"`

Modify `onCreateOptionsMenu`

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_fragment_search, menu);
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_sort, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Your `onOptionItemSelected()` will be like:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if(item.getItemId()==R.id.filter) {
        View menuItemView = findViewById(R.id.filter); // SAME ID AS MENU ID
        showPopup(menuItemView);
    }

    return true;
}
```

Hope it will work....

Comment: I think you should check showPopup method once again. Thank you! and read others answer and comments too.

Comment: @KavyaKashyap What I need to check, can you please tell me? How my code is different as you want.?